# Why is circle CI failing to find rails credentials but spec tests works locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, credentials, circleci

On circle CI I get the following error

```
Failure/Error: hmac_secret = Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:some_key]
NoMethodError:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Is your `credentials.yml` file available there? I assume it's git ignored and therefore not accessible in CircleCI.

Comment: What is the rails environment in circle CI? Maybe you do not have credentials for the given environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails credentials are encrypted in a `credentials.yml.enc` file; this file is safe to add to source control. Rails will also generate a `master.key` file, which is *not* added to your source control.

The CI environment either needs a copy of the `master.key` in the repository when it runs its suite. If that's not possible, you can set a `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env variable with the correct value.

It is also possible that your `credentials` file doesn't have a field for whatever your `Rails.env.to_sym` evaluates to. If the file looks like this:

```
development:
  secret_key: 123
production:
  secret_key: 234
```

using `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:secret_key]` in a `test` env won't give you a hit.